# Python modules download in wrong folder

Tags: python

Whenever i download a module using pip or similar the modules go to my python2.7 folder instead of my python3.8 folder, and due to this whenever i run my code if there is a module not in my 3.8 folder which is in my code i get a ModuleNotFoundError,

eg just recently:

```
File "/Users/tvnsh/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import cli
  File "/Users/tvnsh/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 25, in <module>
    import click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'
```

I know i can just move it from the 2.7 to 3.8 but why is this happening?, and how do i get the modules to download straight to my 3.8 folder instead?.

PS im new to coding and python as a whole so I appreciate your help.

Comment: are you using [virtualenv](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)? If not, you should. if you, is it activated when you are running `pip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how do i get the modules to download straight to my 3.8 folder instead?.*

You might make sure you are downloading to your current version of `python` (i.e. what is launched after typing `python`) by doing

```
python -m pip install click
```

and for `python3` (version which is launched after typing `python3`) by

```
python3 -m pip install click
```

If you want to know more read [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#basic-usage).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a virtual environment, the easiest way is to run

```
pipenv --python 3.8
```

---

Alternatively and as a more persistent solution, you can add the following lines into the pip file:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong version of pip.
Check if you have something called pip2 for python 2.x and pip3 for python 3.x

Otherwise using something like pipenv to not install all dependencies globally would probably be the most recommended option